# Where do I find charts like this for Europe or Global

Tags: landing, aeronautical-charts

I am playing Xplane11 and I am trying to find charts like this [image]

But for Europe or USA and shows every ILS approach, detalied maps etc. For europe I have found one site such as http://www.uvairlines.com/admin/resources/charts-europe.htm but it does not show every airport. Is there a site that shows for any airport ?

Note: I am looking for free sites, not sites like navigraph.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because resource location questions are off-topic as defined in the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Also, if you already know about paid services like Navigraph, why would these even exist if there was a free service out there?

Comment: @Bianfable the commercial services exist because people will pay for convenience, not because the info can't be obtained for free.

Comment: @Bianfable Due to currency I cannot pay that kind of money montly/annualy. Otherwise why wouldn't I use it.

Comment: https://skyvector.com/     https://www.airnav.com/

Comment: They don't have to be current for simulation and video gaming.  That ought to open up options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search term you're looking for is "instrument approach procedure" where sometimes "procedure" will be replaced with "chart" or "plate". Jeppesen provides these commercially for the world in a convenient standardized format for a hefty fee, but the aviation authority for each country also publishes their own versions as part of the ICAO-mandated Aeronautical Information Publication (AIP). In most cases these can be found for free online though it may take some digging.

For the US, the third-party (free) website airnav.com provides a convenient index for the FAA information - search for an airport from their homepage and scroll down for the links under "Instrument Procedures".

Picking a European country at random, Austria's charts are [here](https://eaip.austrocontrol.at/lo/200618/ad_2_lows.htm). Generally you'll want to search for the country's AIP first, then dig through that to look for the instrument procedure charts

I flew myself from California to the UK and back (via Canada, Greenland, Iceland & the Faero Islands) without paying anything for charts this way - paid a lot for fuel though!